# Четные и нечетные элементы в массиве на С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть такая задачка, я написал код в котором элементы спадают и идут по возрастанию.
Нужно чтобы в тех что спадают были только нечетные, а в росте - четные.

> С помощью генератора случайных чисел сформировать массив из 20
>   элементов. Упорядочить элементы массива так, чтобы все элементы с четными
>   номерами были упорядочены по росту, а с нечетными - по убыванию

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int n=21;
    int m[n];
    srand(time(0));
    cout<<"Massiv M:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        m[i]=rand();
        cout<<"m["<<i<<"]= "<<m[i]<<endl;
    }


    // Рост
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<n-i;j++)
        {
            if(m[j]<m[j-1]) { temp=m[j]; m[j]=m[j-1]; m[j-1]=temp;}
        }
    }
    cout<<"Vporyadkovanyj massib po zrostanny:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<m[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    // Убивание
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int g=1;g<n-i;g++)
        {
            if(m[g]>m[g-1]) { temp=m[g]; m[g]=m[g-1]; m[g-1]=temp;}
        }
    }

    cout<<"Vporyadkovanyj massib po spad:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<m[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы немного не так поняли условие задачи: чтобы внутри ОДНОГО массива все элементы с четными индексами располагались в порядке возрастания, а элементы с нечетными индексами в порядке убывания: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` будет отсортирован как: `10 1 8 3 6 5 4 7 2 9`. И замените `m[i]=rand();` на `m[i]=rand()%20 + 1;` где вместо 20 укажите максимальное число. Чтобы вам с большими числами самому не путаться.

Comment: Хорошо, изменил, спасибо. А как мне разделить на четные и не четные?

Comment: Не нужно делить сами элементы на чётные и нечётные - сделайте две сортировки,  одну для элементов с индексами 2*i, другую для  для элементов с индексами 2*i+1

Comment: если вопрос об изяществе не стоит, то можете с помощью дополнительного массива произвести сортировку: копируете вначале четные номера в него, делаете сортировку по возрастанию, затем вставляете по порядку элементы  из отсортированного массива в ваш в четные позиции; затем делаете тоже самое в этот же дополнительный массив только теперь помещаете туда элементы с нечетными индексами; сортируете по убыванию; вставляете этот отсортированный массив в нечетные позиции вашего исходного массива. А если без дополнительного массива, тогда надо немного поднапрячься и подумать...

Comment: Каким способом сделать сортировку?

Comment: ну это как вам нравится: методов сортировки полно. пузырьком самый простой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем `STL` контейнер `list`, функции `copy_if` и `sort` из `algorithm`. [Код](https://ideone.com/JdyX9N):

```
    list<int> tmpN; //создаём список для сортировки

    copy_if(begin(m), end(m), back_inserter(tmpN), [](const int x){ return x%2; }); //нечётные числа

    tmpN.sort([](const int a, const int b){ return a > b; });   //по убыванию

    cout << "Нечётные числа (" << tmpN.size() << " - элементов): ";

    for(int i : tmpN)   //вывод
        cout << i << ' ';

    tmpN.clear();   //очистка списка

    copy_if(begin(m), end(m), back_inserter(tmpN), [](const int x){ return (x+1)%2; }); //чётные числа

    tmpN.sort([](const int a, const int b){ return a < b; });   //по возрастанию

    cout << "\nЧётные числа(" << tmpN.size() << " - элементов): ";

    for(int i : tmpN)   //вывод
        cout << i << ' ';
```

Comment: Мне на С++ нужно. С# не понимаю.

Comment: @Magistr, посмотрите [код](https://ideone.com/JdyX9N). Это и есть C++14 с использованием библиотеки stl.

Comment: У меня код не идет на компиляцию. http://prntscr.com/sscxpx

Comment: Понял, мне нужен С++14

Comment: Вы пишите код на стандарте ниже C++11 ? Возможно у вас не подключена библиотека algorithm.

Comment: Я могу как-то в Dev C++ перейти на С++14?

Comment: Во флагах компиляции можно указать стандарт (-std=c++14). Или [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951376/how-to-change-mode-from-c98-mode-in-dev-c-to-a-mode-that-supports-c0x-ran).

Answer (score 1):

мне кажется, проще сделать проверку i%2 и по факту результата применять сортировку по убыванию или возрастанию на четных и нечетных индексах, соотв.